# JS: inserting element into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have the following function. It is expected to insert *item* into array at position *no*. When *item* is inserted, the last element of the array is dropped, i.e. *array must always have the same length*. Array is taken from string session variable *itemstr* using *split()*. The very first element of the array is to be never changed, so I always call this function starting with `n===1`. The problem is that the function doesn't insert in the sense of `splice()`. It simply changes the value of element *#no*

```
function insert_into_array(no, item)
    {
        var itemarr = sessionStorage.itemstr.split(',');

        if ((no < itemarr.length) && (no > 0)) {
            var i;
            for (i === itemarr.length - 1; i > no; i--) {
                itemarr[i] = itemarr[i - 1]; 
            }
            itemarr[no] = item;
            sessionStorage.itemstr = itemarr.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are avoiding using `splice`?

Comment: When item is inserted, the last elem of array is dropped.Is the array is of fixed length?

Comment: `===` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you have a type:

```
for (i === itemarr.length - 1; i > no; i--) {
```

It should be actually: `i = itemarr.length - 1` and not `i === itemarr.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Not getting what you exactly want.. What i understand is that you need to insert element at position defined by no and remove last element. You can try this in case..

```
 function insert_into_array(no, item)
        {
            var itemarr = sessionStorage.itemstr.split(',');

            if ((no < itemarr.length) && (no > 0)) {
                itemarr .splice(no, 0, item); //Insert element at position defined by #no
                itemarr .pop(); //removes last element
              }
                sessionStorage.itemstr = itemarr.toString();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Culprit for your function is following line

```
for (i === itemarr.length - 1; i > no; i--)
```

here i will be assigned to the value undefined since this is a comparison(===) and not assignment (=). Thus  i(undefined) > no will always be false , so no more loop execution. 
Simply replace comparison with assignment

```
for (i = itemarr.length - 1; i > no; i--)
```

Answer (score -1):

As i understood from the question, you want to insert a variable to an array at a fixed position,and previous content at that position need to shifted and last array value need to be removed.

just use arr.pop() to remove last element and make use of a for loop to shift one position to right. 
using jQuery will be more simple here.

Comment: I'll remove my downvote if you can give one valid explanation of how you can simplify this with jQuery.

Comment: I have done something similar to this using the jQuery slice() method.
That's why i suggested jQuery, please correct me if am wrong. thanks

Comment: [jQuery's slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) works on jQuery collections, not arrays. It isn't usable for the OP's array which is an array of strings. Fortunately ordinary Javascript arrays have [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) already.